# Run Lollipop version apps to lower version apps such as API 8?

Tags: android-studio, material-design

I am very new to Android Studio! I have done phone contacts with the help of card views. I could be able to see output on Emulator (version 21) which I have run app on 21. But now I just need to run lolipop (API 21) version apps on lower version devices like (API 8).

If it runs then can be able to download APK to lower version devices which supports only API 8. The material design and themes should not be changed like I have on API 21. I have added cardView and recycler view libraries to support. Do I need to change or add any other things?

**In Build.gradle,**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.meenar.meen_app3"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

}
```

**In Android Manifest.xml,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.meenar.meen_app3"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-sdk
    tools:node="replace" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Card1Activity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Card2Activity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Card3Activity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Card4Activity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Card5Activity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

In Styles.xml, ie. values-v21 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
</style>

</resources>
```

When I run on API 21 version, it has material design effects - Checkboxes and radiobuttons of cardview:

[image]

Comment: First off you will need to change your minSdkVersion to 8 rather than 19.

Comment: @Joel - Hi, I have changed minSdkVersion as 8 also. But not material design effects are visible

Comment: If you look at this page: https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html You will see that only certain widgets will allow material design below api version 21. You will need to use `Theme.AppCompat` in your `res/values/styles.xml` and include `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'` in your dependencies to use the material design styles that are available.